# Unable to connect to Exchange 2010 server from Entourage 2008

Tags: exchange-2010, microsoft-ftmg-2010, mac

I'm having some issues with setting up Entourage 2008 EWS up to connect with our exchange 2010 server. So I hope someone can answer me the following:

1. I know that there are some issues with our autodiscover, but i should be able to setup EWS without it right?
2. What server information does EWS need to start running? I'm really having a hard time figuring it out? I tried the local server name and then through the our TMG, noting, kinda lost here.
3. All other clients using outlook 2003, are working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Are you having a single Exchange server with CAS/HT/MBX role?
Clients are connecting differently nowdays.

I think Outlook 2003 still connects towards the MBX while Outlook 2007/2010/Entourage connects towards the CAS role.

Is the firewall enabled?

Comment: Yes, it should be. okay, so what can I do? I looked more in to it, and we have office 2010 runnning as well in a small amount. So I'm guessing I'm doing ti wrong. Firewall disabled